# Building an API, should users POST variables or JSON?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, api

I am building my first serious API. I am trying to decide how users should POST data.

I could allow them to POST variables, which is what HTML forms do.

```
param1=foo&param2=bar
```

Or I can let them POST JSON, which also makes sense because I will be returning a JSON response to the user.

```
{"param1":"&","param2":"bar"}
```

Is there a formal standard to which of these should be used? Are there strong arguments towards or against either of these approaches?

Comment: Also consider that the with JSON is easy to build complicated (nested) data structures, while with the form method is probably way too complicated. So you could use both methods, but sometimes JSON might be the mandatory choice.

Comment: The question is really about how the client should encode the data in their request bodies - either as [x-www-form-urlencoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) like a browser would do, or as [json](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JSON is (by far) the most flexible and modern option of the two, so I would go for that. Especially if you have already decided to return a response in JSON.

That said, there's no reason you can't support both, if this is beneficial for the consumers of your API. HTML forms submit their content with an HTTP request where the `Content-Type` HTTP header will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, while the correct content type for JSON is `application/json`.

Some frameworks, e.g. [ASP.NET Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/) offer some automatic *serialization* of the incoming request (whether it is XML or JSON, I'm not sure if this framework supports form encoding), lifting the burden of this task from you.

If you're creating REST APIs, you can use the [Swagger](http://swagger.io/specification/) specification; it's a definition format (YAML) to describe RESTful APIs creating an interface for easily developing and consuming an API by mapping the resources and operations associated with it. It's language agnostic so you can generate services for many Server/Client-side languages, it's readable, and above all generates a nice API specification documentation.

Comment: One thing that might have to be taken into account is the size of the POST data when using query parameters. Some clients may impose a limit on how much they handle. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/146205 for a more detailed write-up.

Comment: @Jensen I don't think the question is about sending POST data as query parameters, it's about sending POST data as a form-encoded body message.

Answer (score 7):

Having them post json let's you be more versatile and precise in the data structures you receive; however, POST variables let your API be easily used by web browsers.

If you know the requests will always be server to server, or you have very complex inputs, I would go with json. If your inputs are very simple, it will make your API more easily used if you use POST vars.

Answer (score 1):

> Or I can let them POST JSON, which also makes sense because I will be
>   returning a JSON response to the user.

Well, the response format should not constrain or condition the request format.

It might interest you the [postel's law, also known as Robustness principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

It is good to support different representantion formats for both request and response. The key of the robustness lays on the strict representantation of the resource (model or data structure), not its format (json, xml, csv).

So, regarding to the question. A good practice could be supporting both (quey strings and request body).

Just a little consideration related to the API security. For endpoints meant to comunicate sensitive data (passwords, tokens, personal data) it's recommended to don't post the data via query strings. Instead use the JSON approach or http headers.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: @Goose, srry. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Posting the json object allows for more flexibility, especially if you want to use DateTime as one of your parameters. The query string is also length limited if the parameters are heavy at all.

However, for simple Post requests you can supply both options, it's an extra method in Asp.Net.